# Identities involving the floor function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Are either of these statements false? if so what is the counter example?

$⌊x − 2⌋ = ⌊x⌋ − 2$

or

for any odd integer $n$, $⌊(n^2/4) + 1⌋ = (n^2+3)/4$

Also I'm struggling to make a proof of either if they are true. I just can't seem to start either of them. for the second all I got is $n = 2k + 1$ and then sub it in but get stuck there.

Any help would be great!

Comment: It seems that both of these statements are true.  The trick, then, is to prove them.  To start, what is the explicit definition of $\lfloor x \rfloor$ that you've been using?

Comment: Jepp, both are true. For the first part note that you can always write $x = n + r$ where $n$ is an integer and $0 \leq r < 1$. Using this representation, try to compute $\lfloor x\rfloor$ and $\lfloor x-2\rfloor$. For the second part if $n = 2k+1$ then $\frac{n^2}{4} = k^2 + k + \frac{1}{4}$, what is the floor of that?

Comment: ahh yes thank you! I just need a little push then I can do it. Just understanding the starting point is where I struggle.

Comment: ok for the first one I did what you said making x = n + r so that no matter what the floor of r is 0 but then I'm just back to my original statement.

Comment: Edit- I think I got it I can just add 2 to both sides to get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Another good way to do this is to use the following property (which could be the definition, depending how you have approached it in your course):

> $\lfloor x\rfloor=a$ if and only if $a$ is an integer and $a\le x<a+1$.

Then for your second example you need to show that

- if $n$ is odd then $(n^2+3)/4$ is an integer;
- we have
  $$\frac{n^2+3}{4}\le\frac{n^2}{4}+1<\frac{n^2+3}{4}+1\ .$$

I think you will find that both of these are quite easy.